# Having clause trouble

Tags: mysql

So using the following 2 tables
Employee:

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
| Fname    | Minit | Lname   | SSN       | Bdate      | Address                  | Sex  | Salary | Superssn  | Dno |
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
| John     | B     | Smith   | 123456789 | 1955-01-09 | 731 Fondren, Cary, NC    | M    |  31500 | 333445555 |   5 |
| Franklin | T     | Wong    | 333445555 | 1945-12-08 | 638 Voss, Cary, NC       | M    |  42000 | 888665555 |   5 |
| Joyce    | A     | English | 453453453 | 1962-07-31 | 5631 Rice, Raleigh, NC   | F    |  26250 | 333445555 |   5 |
| Rameish  | K     | Naraya  | 666884444 | 1952-09-15 | 975 Fire Oak, Angier, NC | M    |  39900 | 333445555 |   5 |
| James    | E     | Borg    | 888665555 | 1927-11-10 | 450 Stone, Cary, NC      | M    |  55000 | NULL      |   1 |
| Jennifer | S     | Wallace | 987654321 | 1931-06-20 | 291 Berry, Garner, NC    | F    |  43000 | 888665555 |   4 |
| Ahmad    | V     | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 1959-03-29 | 980 Dallas, Cary, NC     | M    |  25000 | 987654321 |   4 |
| Alicia   | J     | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 1958-07-19 | 3321 Castle, Apex, NC    | F    |  25000 | 987654321 |   4 |
+----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+-----+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Department:

```
mysql> select * from department
    -> ;
+---------+----------------+-----------+
| dnumber | dname          | mgrssn    |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
|       1 | Headquarters   | 888665555 |
|       2 | Development    | NULL      |
|       3 | Sales          | NULL      |
|       4 | Administration | 987654321 |
|       5 | Research       | 333445555 |
+---------+----------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to combine information using the having clause which department's employees have an average salary greater than 33000.
This is a copy of the output:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| dname        | AVG(salary) |
+--------------+-------------+
| Headquarters |       55000 |
| Research     |       35000 |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Ok where I am so far:

```
mysql> select d.dname, AVG(salary)
    -> from department as d, employee as e
    -> having avg(salary) > 33000
    -> group by d.dname;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near 'group by d.dname' at line 4
mysql> select d.dname, AVG(salary)
    -> from department as d, employee as e
    -> having avg(salary) > 33000
    -> group by ????
```

What am I missing for the group by?

Comment: What is your query so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and all your other questions smell like you're doing some test or course. Shouldn't it be time that you at least *attempt* to solve one of these questions yourself?

```
select
  d.dname,
  AVG(salary)
from
  department d
  inner join employee e on e.Dno = d.dnumber
group by
  d.dname
having
  avg(salary) > 33000
```

First of all, I use d and e as aliases for Department and Employee. You can specify aliases after the table name in the query. You can use them to prefix field names, but you don't have to if that field exists in only one table.

Let's continue with the inner join. There's a relation between the tables. It looks like department.dnumber contains the department number. Also, employee.Dno contains the department number of the employees. By joining the table, you combine the data. The query will return a row for each department and for all employees. The information of the department is duplicated for each employee that is returned.

The the [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function). SQL knows a number of *aggregate* functions. If you select a field or a couple of fields to 'group' by, you can use other fields to 'aggregate' over. So in this case, I group by department name. I earlier said it would the return the department information multiple times, one time for each employee of the department. Now, this step *groups* that information again. It returns the department name only one time, and aggregates the employee information. In this case, I use AVG to calculate the avarage salary, but you could also use `SUM(salary)` to get the total salary of all employees in the department, or `COUNT(*)` to count the number of employees per department.

Comment: Then you would be correct sir/ma'am. How else am I suppose to learn. But being a full time employee and taking full time course load online limits my opportunity to sit in a class and ask the teacher questions. So I would apologize for being a hard working citizen and a full time student, but my plate is already overflowing as is.

Comment: I'm really not looking for just an answer, I have a final for this class coming up and I need to understand "HOW" this works.

Comment: I'm a full time employee and do a study at university in the evening hours, but still I find time to answer your question. I'm not saying you aren't hard working or whatever, I didn't mean to attack you at all. I'm just wondering what you are doing such a course or study for if you're not attempting to learn anything at all. Best case, it's an enormous waste of time and money. Worst case, you tell your employer you've learned to query an avarage salary from a database, and then get fired as soon as they find out you actually *don't* know how to do it.

Comment: why is it {select d.dname} and {inner join employee e on e.dno=d.number}

Comment: I'm sorry I took your words a little offensively when you said I didn't try. I always try before putting anything up here, but with this question, I didn't know where to begin. I can't ask the book questions, and my professor won't answer my question until monday night at best. This site is my only option.

Comment: Ok. Added some explanation.

Comment: Ok so I kinda understand what your saying. I'm not exactly clear on the inner join portion. Also I tried your syntax and only get
`mysql> select d.dname, AVG(salary)
    -> from department d
    -> inner join employee e on e.dno=d.dnumber
    -> having avg(salary) > 33000;
+----------+-------------+
| dname    | AVG(salary) |
+----------+-------------+
| Research |    35956.25 |
+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Yeah, you need `group by` as well. I forgot it at first, but I've added it half an hour ago. Please use the altered version.