# more on group by clause

Tags: mysql

After learning a bit more about group and having clause I was able to knock out another assignment. [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783075/having-clause-trouble)

For the employee table and department table, show departments with 3 or more employees
as shown:

```
+----------------+---------------------+
| dname          | COUNT(employee.dno) |
+----------------+---------------------+
| Administration |                   3 |
| Research       |                   5 |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select d.dname, count(e.dno)
        -> from department d
        -> inner join employee e on e.dno = d.dnumber
        -> group by d.dname
        -> having count(e.dno) > 2;
    +----------------+--------------+
    | dname          | count(e.dno) |
    +----------------+--------------+
    | Administration |            3 |
    | Research       |            4 |
    +----------------+--------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know the Research shows 4 and not 5 like illustrated in the question. Its due to an error on the professor's side when making the problem and rearranging the questions.

Much props to GolezTrol (sorry I can't figure out how to link your name to this)